# After installing Ubuntu the Laptop shuts down

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, shutdown, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 and today three times while I was working the Laptop shuts down unexpected.  I was trying to find something in /var/log but i didn't find what caused the Laptop to shut down. I changed also the Nvidia Driver-390 in Additional Driveras default.

One month ago, only Windows 10 was installed and the same thing was happening. The Laptop was in repair and they changed only the SSD because it had some deffect and updated the Bios Version.

Can you help me please to find what's the problem ? It's something with the Hardware or with OS Ubuntu ?

Acer Aspire F5-771G
Intel Core i7
16 GB DDR4 Memory
SSD 256GB
HDD 1TB

Comment: Are your sure BIOS is updated

Comment: Im not sure, because before I give the Laptop to the repair service, I checked the Bios and it was version 1.27 and I updated to version 1.30. After i got the Laptop back it was the same version 1.27.

Comment: I had similar problem where pc auto restarts after 5 minutes if I use it continuously for more than 8 hours, BIOS update solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to update the Bios. But I'm not sure if Secure Boot should stay enabled or disabled ?